# Как получить обновленные данные таблицы handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Есть таблица с данными. Есть скрипт для фильтрации колонок, при выборе чекбокса с именем колонки она удаляется с таблицы или появляется в зависимости установлен флажок или нет. Вот код:

```
var HIDDING_ROWS = [];

var show = function () {
    var hot = $("#exempel").handsontable('getInstance');
    var newColumns = $.extend(true, [], columns_personage);
    var newHeaders = $.extend(true, [], header_personage);
    for (var i = 0; i < HIDDING_ROWS.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < newColumns.length; j++) {
            if (HIDDING_ROWS[i] === newColumns[j].data) {
                newColumns.splice(j, 1);
                newHeaders.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    hot.updateSettings({
        columns: $.extend(true, [], newColumns),
        colHeaders: $.extend(true, [], newHeaders)
    });
    hot.render();
};

$('.checkbox-inline input').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).prop('checked');
    var className = $(this).attr('class');
    if (value) {
        HIDDING_ROWS.push(className);
        show();
    }
    else {
        var index = HIDDING_ROWS.indexOf(className);
        if (index < 0)return;
        HIDDING_ROWS.splice(index, 1);
        show();
    }
});
```

После удаления колонки я пытаюсь получить данные таблицы:

```
var row = $("#exempel").data('handsontable');
var tableData = row.getData();
```

И получаю обект в котором есть свойства которые относятся к колонкам которые я удалил.
Как получит данные без тех свойств которые удалились (скрылись) из таблицы?

Comment: Вы же не удаляете строки, а «скрываете» их. Притом даже это делаете неявно. Вам предстоит или переделать архитектуру или вручную удалять значения, что присутствуют в массиве скрытых строк.

Comment: А как удалить их явно?